# getting focal length to calculate distance from Mediapipe iris in browser?

Tags: javascript, computer-vision, mediapipe

as mentioned [here](https://ai.googleblog.com/2020/08/mediapipe-iris-real-time-iris-tracking.html?m=1) **(sec:Depth-from-Iris: Depth Estimation from a Single Image)** the iris model could be used to get distance from screen using triangle similarity. I'm trying to implement this on a browser webapp using mediapipe iris but not sure how to get the camera focal length. Which camera capture API can I use to get the focal length of user's camera ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no API available that can give you this information. When I tried to answer the same problem I looked at this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices

Which gives you a list of [device information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDeviceInfo). From that you might be able to guess i.e. if the device.label is FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in) you can guess the focal length to be 50 mm.

But this isn't usually the best option so what I'd do is just have a field that lets the user specify focal length and sensor size. Then you can calculate focal length in px for that particular example.